# sorting array in mips (assembly)

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, mips

im in a class learning assembly using mips. I am working on sorting an array of numbers and i think that I have the method working correctly, but just a bit of trouble. I do not know how to check when im sorted fully. Im using a pretty rudimentary method for sorting, but that is all that we have learned thus far. Also, i do not know how to output the numbers to check to see if it is sorted. Im used to Java and such so assembly is kinda throwing me for a spin. Here is my code thus far:

```
    .text
    .globl main
main:       la  $a0, Array             # sets the base address of the array to $a0
loop:       lw  $t0, 0($a0)             # sets $t0 to the current element in array
            lw  $t1, 4($a0)         # sets $t1 to the next element in array
            blt $t1, $t0, swap      # if the following value is greater, swap them
            addi    $a0, $a0, 4     # advance the array to start at the next location from last time
            j   loop                  # jump back to loop so we can compare next two elements

swap:       sw  $t0, 4($a0)         # store the greater numbers contents in the higher position in array (swap)
            sw  $t1, 0($a0)         # store the lesser numbers contents in the lower position in array (swap)
            li  $a0, 0                 # resets the value of $a0 back to zero so we can start from beginning of array
            j   loop                  # jump back to the loop so we can go through and find next swap

            .data

Array:      .word   14, 12, 13, 5, 9, 11, 3, 6, 7, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1
```

thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Looks to me like some sort of bubble sort. Why do you jump to the beginning of the array after swapping? Just keep swapping elements as long as arr[i] > arr[i+1], after each iteration, one more element is in its final position in the end of the array. With this approach, you repeat that n times (where n is the array's length), and you are guaranteed to have the array sorted in the end.

Comment: Also, about writing output to the user, maybe this will help: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/42881-mips-assembly-take-user-input-and-write-to-the-console/

Comment: well if i were to keep going instead of hoping back to the beginning of the array how do you recommend that i would know im at the end of the array, and how would i know when it is sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html) explains how to print to the screen in a MIPS simulator like [QTSPIM](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://spimsimulator.sourceforge.net/&ei=im9XUsnXE5Lb4APHwIHwCg&usg=AFQjCNGN7AI4es3oD5n4Q8pF2rB2CQ-E_Q&sig2=_pvtl8_O4UgbJQNApuuEDg&bvm=bv.53899372,d.dmg) or [MARS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/&ei=pm9XUu7eEffj4APIhIHoBg&usg=AFQjCNGNWrmeHgY8UzCq6kwpee2tdKLpqw&sig2=iAWY5ctd96PWvs_1-cwMpA&bvm=bv.53899372,d.dmg).

As for the code, there were a few bugs. The line `li  $a0, 0` is overwriting the work done by the initial `la  $a0, Array` instruction because the `li` is setting the base address of your array to 0. Instead, you should move the `la` instruction into the loop so that `$a0` is properly reset to the base address of `Array` after iterating over the entire array, and remove the `li` instruction. You also will need to add in a condition for when your program has completed the sort. I would suggest the following revisions (tested with SPIM):

```
main:
    la  $t0, Array      # Copy the base address of your array into $t1
    add $t0, $t0, 40    # 4 bytes per int * 10 ints = 40 bytes                              
outterLoop:             # Used to determine when we are done iterating over the Array
    add $t1, $0, $0     # $t1 holds a flag to determine when the list is sorted
    la  $a0, Array      # Set $a0 to the base address of the Array
innerLoop:                  # The inner loop will iterate over the Array checking if a swap is needed
    lw  $t2, 0($a0)         # sets $t0 to the current element in array
    lw  $t3, 4($a0)         # sets $t1 to the next element in array
    slt $t5, $t2, $t3       # $t5 = 1 if $t0 < $t1
    beq $t5, $0, continue   # if $t5 = 1, then swap them
    add $t1, $0, 1          # if we need to swap, we need to check the list again
    sw  $t2, 4($a0)         # store the greater numbers contents in the higher position in array (swap)
    sw  $t3, 0($a0)         # store the lesser numbers contents in the lower position in array (swap)
continue:
    addi $a0, $a0, 4            # advance the array to start at the next location from last time
    bne  $a0, $t0, innerLoop    # If $a0 != the end of Array, jump back to innerLoop
    bne  $t1, $0, outterLoop    # $t1 = 1, another pass is needed, jump back to outterLoop
```

Be sure to check out [this link](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) for additional examples and explanations on what each MIPS instruction does.

Answer (score 1):

Coding direct in assembly is a pain. What I do instead is start with an algorithm (psuedocode or actual code) then translate systematically, as if I am a compiler. I will ignore the input and output stuff and focus on a function that sorts.

You would call in a high-level lanaguage like C as:

```
insertionsort(data, N);
```

where `data` is an integer array and `N` the number of elements (there are no size attributes at machine level).

Since the function calls nothing, it needs no stack frame. Observe the standard MIPS conventions of using `$t` registers so you are not trashing anything anyone else relies on and pass in parameters in `$a0` and `$a1` in that order.

Step 1: get an algorithm. Here’s one from [Wikipedia][1] for insertion sort:

```
i ← 1
while i < length(A)
    x ← A[i]
    j ← i - 1
    while j >= 0 and A[j] > x
        A[j+1] ← A[j]
        j ← j - 1
    end while
    A[j+1] ← x
    i ← i + 1
end while
```

Step 2: paste into a text file, turn all lines into comments and systematically convert to assembly. I use templates for things like loops that take the guess work out of coding (see my [free book](http://homes.cs.ru.ac.za/philip/Courses/CS2-arch-C/) for examples). I will just give the finished product here; to call it, you need to put the start address of the array into `$a0` and its size in `$a1`, then `jal insertionsort`:

```
# algorithm for insertion sort
# from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort
# usage: insertionsort (a,N)
# pass array start in $a0, size in elements, N in $a1
# Philip Machanick
# 30 April 2018

            .globl insertionsort

            .text

# leaf function, no stack frame needed
# Registers:
#   $a0: base address; $a1: N
#   $t0: i
#   $t1: j
#   $t2: value of A[i] or A[j]
#   $t3: value of x (current A[i])
#   $t4: current offset of A[i] or A[j] as needed
insertionsort:
# i ← 1
       li $t0, 1
# while i < N
       j Wnext001        # test before 1st iteration
Wbody001:                # body of loop here
      sll $t4, $t0, 2    # scale index i to offset
      add $t4, $a0, $t4  # address of a[i]
#     x ← A[i]
      lw $t3, 0($t4)
#     j ← i - 1
      addi $t1, $t0, -1
#     while j >= 0 and A[j] > x
       j Wnext002        # test before 1st iteration
Wbody002:                # body of loop here
#         A[j+1] ← A[j]
          sll  $t4, $t1, 2        # scale index j to offset
          add $t4, $a0, $t4       # address of a[j]
          lw $t2, 0($t4)          # get value of A[j]
          addi $t4, $t4, 4        # offset of A[j+1]
          sw $t2, 0($t4)          # assign to A[j+1]
#         j ← j - 1
          addi $t1, $t1, -1
#     end while
Wnext002: # construct condition, j >= 0 and A[j] > x
          blt $t1, $zero Wdone002 # convert to: if j < 0 break from loop #####
          sll  $t4, $t1, 2        # scale index j to offset
          add $t4, $a0, $t4       # address of a[j]
          lw $t2, 0($t4)          # A[j]
          bgt $t2, $t3, Wbody002  # no need to test j >= 0, broke from loop already if false
Wdone002:                         # branch here to short-circuit and
#     A[j+1] ← x
          add  $t4, $t1, 1        # scale index j+1 to offset
          sll  $t4, $t4, 2        # scale index j to offset
          add $t4, $a0, $t4       # address of a[j+1]
          sw $t3, 0($t4)          # A[j+1] becomes x
#     i ← i + 1
          addi $t0, $t0, 1
# end while
Wnext001: blt $t0,$a1, Wbody001  # i < N easy this time
          jr $ra                 # return to caller
```

Longer than the other examples – but if you start from an algorithm and translate you are less likely to go wrong. This can go in a separate file if your assembler respects the `.globl` directive, which makes the name visible in other files.

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort – actually from  Cormen, Thomas H.; Leiserson, Charles E.; Rivest, Ronald L.; Stein, Clifford (2001). "Section 2.1: Insertion sort". Introduction to Algorithms (2nd ed.). MIT Press and McGraw-Hill. pp. 15–21

Comment: Nice.  Worth mentioning that if you know a loop will run at least 1 iteration (i.e. the while condition is true the first time) you can optimize out the `j` to the loop condition at the bottom.  Or you can peel check-for-zero-iterations instead of jumping into the loop, like compilers usually do, so it's like `if(foo) { do{}while(foo); }`. [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47783926).  +1 for a nice systematic way to convert pseudo-code into asm with variable in registers and clean loop structure. Even though pointer increments are better

Comment: This would be easier to read and more efficient if fewer instructions were spent on array indexing.  e.g. `addi $t4, $t4, 4` should be replaced by using the offset in the next addressing mode, like `4($t4)` instead of `0`.  Also, just using byte offsets all the time would remove lots of shift.  Or even better, make `i` and `j` pointers instead of indices: everything works identically except you don't have to add to the array base. Instead of comparing against 0 and length, you compare against base and an end-pointer you calculate once. (MIPS has `bltz` in hardware, so you do miss out on that.)

Comment: Right but I wanted to illustrate the most direct translation from C-like code. Using an offset in the instruction is a neat trick provided you know he distance apart of two array references (here, A[j] and A[j+1]). if you don’t know the distance apart you can’t code the offset into the instruction.

Comment: The code in the question already uses a `4($a0)` addressing mode.  Using the offset field of lw/sw can easily be part of a naive direct translation from C to asm, if the memory addressing C expression includes any constant parts, like the `+1`.  MIPS even has different mnemonics for registers vs. constants (`addu` vs. `addiu`) so it doesn't make sense to avoid using the power of MIPS's only addressing mode when you already need a special instruction for adding a constant.

Comment: I’m not seeing where in the code `4($a0)` is used. I wanted to keep the translation very simple. My book goes into issues like pointer arithmetic. Since this discussion is useful for amplifying alternatives I won’t alter my code even if it could be made more concise. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Hit control-f and copy/paste `4($a0)` and your web browser will highlight that in the code in the original question for you.  It's used along with a load from `0($a0)` to get a pair of adjacent elements in a sane compact efficient way.  (And in a store that's conditionally branched over).

Comment: Thanks, I misread your comment as relating to my code.

Answer (score -1):

.data

value: .word 0x3

Array: .word   0x14, 0x12, 0x13, 0x05

.text

.globl main

main:  la  $a0, Array

```
   lw  $t3,value
```

l1:    lw  $t0, 0($a0)

```
   lw  $t1, 4($a0)     

   blt $t1, $t0, swap   

   addi    $a0, $a0, 4

   addi $t3,$t3,-1     

   bne  $t3,$zero,l1

   jr $ra
```

swap:   sw  $t0, 4($a0)

```
    sw  $t1, 0($a0)    

    j   l1
```