# PLP Tool Bubble Sort

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this code that I found from: [sorting array in mips (assembly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212544/sorting-array-in-mips-assembly)

I am trying to convert it from MIPS language to PLP (which I know they are both assembly language), the `la` instruction is what's throwing me off. What would be the equivalent for of MIPS `la` for PLP Tool?

The code is:

```
main:
    la  $t0, Array      # Copy the base address of your array into $t1
    add $t0, $t0, 40    # 4 bytes per int * 10 ints = 40 bytes 

outterLoop:             # Used to determine when we are done iterating over the Array
    add $t1, $0, $0     # $t1 holds a flag to determine when the list is sorted
    la  $a0, Array      # Set $a0 to the base address of the Array

innerLoop:                  # The inner loop will iterate over the Array checking if a swap is needed
    lw  $t2, 0($a0)         # sets $t0 to the current element in array
    lw  $t3, 4($a0)         # sets $t1 to the next element in array
    slt $t5, $t2, $t3       # $t5 = 1 if $t0 < $t1
    beq $t5, $0, continue   # if $t5 = 1, then swap them
    add $t1, $0, 1          # if we need to swap, we need to check the list again
    sw  $t2, 4($a0)         # store the greater numbers contents in the higher position in array (swap)
    sw  $t3, 0($a0)         # store the lesser numbers contents in the lower position in array (swap)

continue:
    addi $a0, $a0, 4            # advance the array to start at the next location from last time
    bne  $a0, $t0, innerLoop    # If $a0 != the end of Array, jump back to innerLoop
    bne  $t1, $0, outterLoop    # $t1 = 1, another pass is needed, jump back to outterLoop
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/progressive-learning-platform/wiki/UserManual#Pseudo-Operations) states you can use the `li` instruction:

`li $rd, label` is a pseudoinstruction that expands to:

```
lui $rd, (label & 0xff00) >> 16
ori $rd, label & 0x00ff
```

This loads the address of the `label` to a register `$rd` to be used as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Where li is load immediate
lw is load word or sw store word
la is loading the address (more direct than li or lw)

la  $t0, var1
copy RAM address of var1 (presumably a label defined in the program) into register $t0