# How to find Max and Min values in Integer and Float arrays in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am VERY much a beginner to MIPS and I am very confused. What I need to do is find the maximum and minimum values in both an integer array and a float array. I attempted to adapt an answer from [sorting array in mips (assembly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212544/sorting-array-in-mips-assembly) to try to sort the array, but I'm not sure where to go from here, plus, I know my trying to sort the float array is very wrong. I apologize as I know what I have written is probably very dumb, but any help would be MUCH appreciated!

```
.data
intArray: .word 3, 53, -76, 34, 643, -234, 143, 2, -33, 64
floatArray: .float 43.53, 45.2244, 25, 64.035, 328, 23.85, 23.86544, 93.4, 46.6543256, 0.00345

.text

main:
la $t0, intArray
add $t0, $t0, 40

intOuterSort:
    add $t1, $0, $0
    la $a0, intArray

intInnerSort:
    lw $t2, 0($a0)
    lw $t3, 4($a0)
    slt $t4, $t2, $t3
    beq $t4, 0, intNext
    add $t1, $0, 1
    sw $t2, 4($a0)
    sw $t3, 0($a0)

intNext:
    addi $a0, $a0, 4
    bne $a0, $t0, intInnerSort
    bne $t1, $0, intOuterSort

la $t0, floatArray
add.s $f2, $f2, 40

floatOuterSort:
    add.s $f4, $0, $0
    la $a0, floatArray

floatInnerSort:
    li.s $f6, 0($a0)
    li.s $f8, 4($a0)
    slt $f10, $f6, $f8
    beq $f10, 0, floatNext
    add.s $f4, $0, 1
    s.s $f6, 4($a0)
    s.s $f8, 0($a0)

floatNext:
    add.s $a0, $a0, 4
    bne $a0, $f2, floatInnerSort
    bne $f4, $0, floatOuterSort
```

Answer (score 2):

You definitely do not need to sort array in order to find max and min and your code is uselessly complex.

Just traverse the array once and remember what are the max and min values.

Here is a possible version for intSearch

```
.data
intArray:       .word 3, 53, -76, 34, 643, -234, 143, 2, -33, 64
floatArray:     .float 43.53, 45.2244, 25, 64.035, 328, 23.85, 23.86544, 93.4, 46.6543256, 0.00345
minInt:         .word 0x80000000
maxInt:         .word 0x7fffffff
minFloat:       .float -3.40e+38f
maxFloat:       .float 3.40e+38f

.text

intSearch:
        la   $t0, intArray        ; $t0->@intarray
        addi $t1, $0, 10          ; $t1->N(=10)
        add  $t2, $0, $0          ; $t2->i(=0)
        lw   $t3, minInt($0)      ; $t3->imax (initialised to a small value)
        lw   $t4, maxInt($0)      ; $t4->imin (initialised to a large value)

iloop:  lw   $t5, 0($t0)          ; $t5->intArray[i]
        bgt  $t5, $t4, skipImin   ; $t5 <=? iMin
        move $t5, $t4             ; yes update min
skipIMin:                         ; skip if $t5>iMin
        blt  $t5, $t3, skipIMax   ; $t5 >= iMax
        move $t5, $t3             ; yes update max
skipIMax:                         ; skip if $t5<iMax
        addi $t2, $t2, 1          ; i++
        addi $t0, $t0, 4          ; @intArray++
        blt  $t2, $t1, iloop      ; i<n -> iloop
#       min is in $t4, max in $t3
```

The float version is similar (and left as an exercise).

Comment: The initial values can be created with only immediates (`lui $t3, 0x8000` / `subiu $t4, $t3, 1`).  Or by loading the first element if you can already assume non-zero size.  Anyway, there's no need to have the int initializers in static storage, vs. as assemble-time constants.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, but this unfortunately did not work as minInt and maxInt never updated.

Comment: They are not supposed to be updated. It is just the initial value. min result is initialized as the maxInt and max as the minInt. But as Peter Cordes spotted, the code can be replaced by an initialisation at the value of the first element of array. Remove `intMin and intMax, lw $t3... and lw $t4...` and replace them with `lw $t3, 0($t0)`  `move $t4, $t3` (or `lw $t4, 0($t0)`)